# Coreplot for implementing barchart

Tags: core-plot

Am implementing  barchart using coreplot...am getting the errors bellow which am unable to debug. Can anybody please help me out with the solution for this..Tried all  ways but still couldn find the solution.

Ld /Users/MacMini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DashBoard-cmeoxsnbrnrzrkcwmgmfxqlfuzvo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DashBoard.app/DashBoard normal i386
    cd /Users/MacMini/Desktop/DashBoard
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -L/Users/MacMini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DashBoard-cmeoxsnbrnrzrkcwmgmfxqlfuzvo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/MacMini/Desktop/DashBoard -F/Users/MacMini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DashBoard-cmeoxsnbrnrzrkcwmgmfxqlfuzvo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/MacMini/Desktop/DashBoard -filelist /Users/MacMini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DashBoard-cmeoxsnbrnrzrkcwmgmfxqlfuzvo/Build/Intermediates/DashBoard.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DashBoard.build/Objects-normal/i386/DashBoard.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -ObjC -all_load -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework QuartzCore -lCorePlot-CocoaTouch -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/MacMini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DashBoard-cmeoxsnbrnrzrkcwmgmfxqlfuzvo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DashBoard.app/DashBoard

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CPTDecimalFromDouble", referenced from:
      -[Barchart viewDidLoad] in Barchart.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTGraphHostingView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Barchart.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTXYGraph", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Barchart.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTPlotRange", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Barchart.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTBarPlot", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Barchart.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1):

This page (in the comments section) may help you with that: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications

And this is a previous Stack Overflow question that looks like yours: 
[Using Core Plot iPhone - Linker error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685363/using-core-plot-iphone-linker-error)

Here are some fixes I found on the pages above:

- In CorePlot-CocoaTouch project settings, change ***iOS Deployment Target*** to **3.2**

  - change ***Build Active Architecture Only*** to **No** for all configurations
  - change ***C/C++ Compiler Version*** from GCC 4.2 to **LLVM GCC 4.2**
- Reinstall Core-Plot after downloading its latest stable version

Comment: Hi,I tried with all these settings still am getting same error.Coreplot is working for the sample barchart application ..but when I use coreplot in my application it gives these linking errors

Comment: After trying coreplot install by using SDk as givein in wiki am getting error as:

Comment: ld: duplicate symbol _squareOfDistanceBetweenPoints in /Users/MacMini/Desktop/DashBoard 1/CorePlotInstall_DB/iosbinaries/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a(CPScatterPlot.o) and /var/folders/8B/8BGab5iaFeeebTcSD9rTwU+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.3-bubbnicuystyimgjljhyzsdbfqsf/usr/lib/libCorePlot.a(CPScatterPlot.o) for architecture i386
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
Command 
how to solve this?

Comment: You could try changing C/C++ Compiler Version back to its original value

Comment: your answer was helpful..Thank U.Actually I deleted the contents of framework search path(some unknown thing had automatically generated)..then graph got executed.