# duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, core-plot, esri-arc-engine

I am facing duplicate symbols issue during use of Core plot API and ESRI map Arc GIS API.
In my app I am using Core plot and ArcGIS API. To provide support for 64 bit device, I have download new API for ArcGI (ESRI map) and accordingly update CorePlot API for 64 bit. After making changes I am facing issue:

error description are here:

```
duplicate symbol _squareOfDistanceBetweenPoints in:
    /Users/xxxx/Library/SDKs/ArcGIS/iOS/ArcGIS.framework/ArcGIS(AGSCPTUtilities.o)
    /Users/xxxx/Desktop/18 Nov/SCM_iPad/SCM/CorePlot/coreplot_new.a(CPTUtilities.o)
duplicate symbol _niceNum in:
    /Users/xxxx/Library/SDKs/ArcGIS/iOS/ArcGIS.framework/ArcGIS(AGSCPTAxis.o)
    /Users/xxxx/Desktop/18 Nov/SCM_iPad/SCM/CorePlot/coreplot_new.a(CPTAxis.o)
duplicate symbol _CreateRoundedRectPath in:
    /Users/xxxx/Library/SDKs/ArcGIS/iOS/ArcGIS.framework/ArcGIS(AGSCPTPathExtensions.o)
    /Users/xxxx/Desktop/18 Nov/SCM_iPad/SCM/CorePlot/coreplot_new.a(CPTPathExtensions.o)
duplicate symbol _AddRoundedRectPath in:
    /Users/xxxx/Library/SDKs/ArcGIS/iOS/ArcGIS.framework/ArcGIS(AGSCPTPathExtensions.o)
    /Users/xxxx/Desktop/18 Nov/SCM_iPad/SCM/CorePlot/coreplot_new.a(CPTPathExtensions.o)
duplicate symbol _MyCGPathApplierFunc in:
    /Users/xxxx/Library/SDKs/ArcGIS/iOS/ArcGIS.framework/ArcGIS(NSCoderExtensions.o)
    /Users/xxxx/Desktop/18 Nov/SCM_iPad/SCM/CorePlot/coreplot_new.a(NSCoderExtensions.o)
ld: 5 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If anyone face issue please suggest. I am unable to figure out what is duplicate in those API Earlier these two working fine (OLD api without 64 bit support)

Comment: There seem to be a number of functions (e.g. `CreateRoundedRectPath`) that exist in both frameworks. It's possible that one framework is contained within the other, meaning that you'd only need to include one of them.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660199/coreplot-for-implementing-barchart

Comment: search for the duplicate symbols (_squareOfDistanceBetweenPoints, _niceNum....) if they are implemented(i think these are methods) two times remove one of them..

Comment: Is there any way to remove from either any one of them library..

Comment: It's unusual to get duplicate symbols from *libraries*.  By default, the linker picks one and considers the dependency satisfied.  Are you using any link flags to force loading of library symbols (-ObjC, -all_load...)?  Also, have you tried building without coreplot?

Comment: I fixed the issue by renaming Coreplot library methods and recompile it and create new library and used it.

Answer (score 8):

You might have imported the .m instead of the .h file

Answer (score 0):

You might have added any Typedef function in .H file and have imported .H in many classes.

In my case it was an issue,

```
ShadowASettings ShadowSettingsMake(CGSize shadowSize, CGFloat shadowOpacity, CGFloat shadowRadius){
    ShadowASettings settings;
    settings.shadowOffset = shadowSize;
    settings.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity;
    settings.shadowRadius = shadowRadius;
    return settings;
}
```

I wrote this function in `ABC.h`
and then I imported `ANC.h` in my `HomeVC.h` and `XYZ.h`
So, then I simply move this function to .m of that class as it was only used in .m